PTC Sensing circuitry
I'm trying to replicate a classic car coolant temp sensor. It hasn't been produced in over 20 years.
The original is a very linear PTC sensor with R25=300 Ω and a coefficient of 1,714 Ω/°C.
How can one build such a sensor?
I doubt I can find a thermistor or RTD that is an exact match. So some circuitry would be needed in which case what can I do to get a thermistor or RTD to follow the curve I need using only passive components?
EDIT: adding information
The device is set to operate in the coolant loop of an gasoline engine. It is both cooled and heated by it.
The device is 5V DC powered, and goes to ground.
As a reference and based on AEC-Q200 the expected temperature range is -40 °C to +125 °C (-40 °F to +257 °F). I think it's a bit large for the classic car application as it's likely they won't go out in -40 °C snowy days and they'll explode their engine before 125 °C.
Here is a graph of temp/resistance given by the manufacturer. I'm sorry about the quality.

The manufacturer also supplied 3 resistance range for 3 temperature which I have put in an excel sheet here:

Based on those I was able to get the following linear function:
RESISTANCE = 1,714 × TEMP°C + 255,714
Moreover we can see the margin for a given temperature is 15 Ω. With the coefficient that means the precision is about 8.8 °C.
At -40 °C, which is the lowest of lowest temperature it could have seen when new, it would give 187 Ω. At 5 V that would be 27 mA of draw.
At normal engine operating temperature of 90 °C that would be 410 Ω so 12 mA of draw.
I'm really trying my best here. Do not hesitate if I have forgotten something, made a mistake or if you need additional info.

I'd try utilizing an OP-Amp in differential mode and a PT100.
Multiply dR/dT by ≈4.45 to achieve 1.714 Ω/°C.

But passive bridges are linear only over a small range. you have no specs for range

What temperature range does this operate in? What current (roughly) goes through it?

You'd need a temperature to resistance graph to first see what the device can do.

I have added as much information and my own findings in an edit, waiting for review. Sorry I didn't put everything in the initial post I was trying to be very synthetic as to avoid being the guy that asks you to do the whole ob for them.

Thanks Velvet for the formatting. It is much nicer to read, I didn't think of doing it that way.

Depending on the current and temperature range, you can try 3 Nickel RTDs 1k ohm @ 0'C in parallel with 1k ohm @ 0'C + 500 ohm @ 0'C platinum RTDs.
That's a total of 5 RTDs at about $3-4 each in small quantity.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I calculate a (nominal) error of +9 ohms at 25'C and 0 at 125'C.
There are some nicer Ni RTDs made similarly to the Pt types, but the manufacturer (or seller) has not made the curves readily available so I couldn't consider them. You might want to persist and do your own calculations.

This is indeed the kind of setup I was thinking in my head. Thanks a lot for the idea and the proposed components as it was very hard to consider which could correspond  to the needs!
The error margin is within need so it's great. I don't think it needs nicer stuff. Thanks!

You're welcome. The SOT23s are not the nicest to deal with unless you make a PCB and even then..

A PCB was in the talks anyway. It's supposed to be mounted in a brass fitting and sealed with epoxy. I'm not sure the place i'll have to work with. I just hope the price is within the budget of the club members. It'll always be better than no sensor for sure. Thanks again.

Out of curiosity, what kind of car is this for?

Of course. This is not a particular car nor engine, it is for a fuel injection system called "Renix" an 1980s alliance of Renault and Bendix. In practice it came on period Renaults, Volvo 480 and Jeep Cherokee XJ. The sensors is for an alliance of clubs of Renaults that need this sensor. It's likely we'll also offer them for sale for non-members as a mean to finance the club.
